# bootstrap in view of 768px, the image will not be displayed

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, grid, breakpoints

I'm currently working with bootstrap grid system and got the following problem:
the solution should be work like that: http://ciiznv.axshare.com/#c=2

```
     <div  class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bg-two col-sm-height col-middle nopadding">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-height  col-middle">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2>Text one</h2>
                    <p>lorem ipsum dorem</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-height  col-middle nopadding ">
            <div class="item nopadding">
                <div class="content">                    
                <img class="lazyload" sizes="(min-width: 40em) 80vw, 100vw"
            srcset="http://lorempixel.com/356/150/ 375w, http://lorempixel.com/480/150/ 480w, http://lorempixel.com/768/250/ 768w, http://lorempixel.com/480/480/ 800w" alt="a picture" />
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>    
    </div>



    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bg-three col-sm-height col-middle nopadding">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-height  col-middle">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2>Text two</h2>
                    <p>lorem ipsum dorem dolor</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-height col-middle  nopadding">
            <div class="item nopadding">
                <div class="content">              
                <img class="lazyload" sizes="(min-width: 40em) 80vw, 100vw"
            data-srcset="http://lorempixel.com/356/150/ 375w, http://lorempixel.com/480/150/ 480w, http://lorempixel.com/768/250/ 768w, http://lorempixel.com/480/480/ 800w" alt="a picture" />
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>    
    </div>

</div>
```

But in view of 768px, the image will not be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the .img-responsive class on your images.
See this [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/qsaSkkYlGD)